# Catch an Ajax Query POST error doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I wrote some code that enters data into my sql database using JQuery and PHP and it works.
However, I need the error block of the Ajax request to be executed when the database server is offline, sql throws an error, or whenever there should be an error.

The problem is, that the error-block of the ajax request never is executed. Always just the success block. No matter if the sql query is wrong or the database server is offline.

I have tried it with a fail-block and with jQuery.$.get() but that doesn't work either. But I prefer an ajax request anyway.

I have written the following code so far:

```
//JavaScript-function to insert data into a database. The parameter is an SQL-INSERT statement.
function insertIntoDatabase(sqlQuery)
{
    var result;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../../general/clientHelper.php",
        data: {sql: sqlQuery},
        async: false,
        error: function()
        {
            if(sqlQuery.split(" ")[0] != "INSERT") console.log("SQL-Query is not an INSERT statement");
            result = false;
        },
        success: function()
        {
            result = true;
        }
    });
    
    return result;
}
```

```
<?php

//clientHelper.php - Insert data into the database.

if(isset($_POST['sql'])) insertIntoDatabase($_POST['sql']);
function insertIntoDatabase($sqlQuery)
{
    $ip = "10.10.10.1";
    $port = 3306;
    $username = "candidate";
    $password = "candidate";
    $dbname = "cqtsdb";

    $connection = new mysqli($ip, $username, $password, $dbname, $port);
    $connection->query($sqlQuery);
    $connection->close();
    
    exit();
}
?>
```

I don't know what to do now :/ Please help <3

Comment: Why don't you check the value of `sqlQuery` BEFORE making the AJAX request?

Comment: The `error:` callback is only executed if there's an HTTP error, not a PHP error.

Comment: it would be better to send only the data to the backend, and create the sql query in the backend, your actual code is very vulnerable, any user can send any sql query to the backend, imagine `SHOW TABLES` and then `DELETE FROM some_table` , ...

Comment: Never ever accept SQL queries on server side. I mean - why would you?
So what @yassinefikri said. Plus please use **prepared statements** (see https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and **check for errors** (see https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I found out that if I add one parameter to the success function it gets filled with the text of an error if one has occurred. If everything is right the text is just "". So I didn't have to do anything else than check for it :)

```
success: function(data)
{
    if(data == "") result = true; 
    else  result = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the query result, if it was successful then return a certain value to ajax like 1, if it wasn't, return 0.
Then in ajax success function check that value and show a message accordingly or whatever you want to do.

I use procedural PHP and I do it this way

```
function leave($msg, $conn, $type){
    //$msg is the message I want to display to the user.
    //$type is the query result type I explained above.
    //$conn is to close the connection.
    echo json_encode(array(
        "msg" => $msg,
        "type" => $type
    ));
    mysqli_close($conn);
    exit();
}
```

call this function that way

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if ($result) {
        leave('done', $conn, 1);
    } else {
        leave('something went wrong', $conn, 0);
    }
```

check the value like that:

```
...
success: function (response) {
      if(response.type == 1){
          // do smth
      }
      else if(repsonse.type == 0){
          // do another thing
      }
    },
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your suggestion was a good idea, but I had a few problems implementing it. But then by chance I came up with a very simple solution. If you want to see how, I've posted an answer.

Comment: Glad it helped.